# How did this fairing get a scratch here?

Tags: motorcycle, paint-scratches

I had just purchased this bike a couple of weeks before, however I just noticed this scratch on my faring , on the left side near to the visor. Can anybody tell me how this occurred? And how can it be repaired? 
(The vehicle hasn't met with any collisions during cornering or anything)[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Some A**hole with a key or a van door...

Comment: Or, perhaps, the previous owner leaning the bike carelessly on a stucco wall, and forgetting to tell you about it...

Answer (score 0):

How about a car mirror, a shopping cart, another bike, a baby elephant's tusks etc etc. 
The list can be quite long here. 
If the scratch has another color (i can see some white) on it, it is probably from another vehicle but the list still stays long. (motorcycle, car, van, bus, bicycle etc)
I should consider it a bad scratch but is doesn't seem to compromise any rigidity of the plastic part, so you can take it to a special paint shop for re-painting which will be costly because the whole part has to be removed, gritted repainted and baked OR you could try to get some of these scratch removing creams that will actually MELT the color around it so you can rub it over and covering it

OR you could just carefully paint it over with some nail polish (done that on my WHITE motorcycle and with some care it was unnoticeable) that would match your color (you can even mix multiple ones to match it) and let it be.

Finally you could just let it be.

Comment: Hmm, the white color may be the base coat or material showing through, not paint left by another object...

Comment: Agreed @SolarMike but it will be easy to distinguish the case depending on the scratch depth. Most of the motorcycle paintable plastics are abs which is commonly black. Still if the scratch is deep enough  you can see if this is the underneath plastic color or just a "left over" from contact and friction.

Answer (score 0):

The question of how makes this very much opinion based.

How it actually happened will be that the paintwork came into contact with something that damaged the finish.  Beyond that, it's impossible for someone sitting at a computer screen to know, especially when the owner of the vehicle doesn't know.

As for repair, remove or mask off the fairing and re-paint it.

Comment: "...the owner of the vehicle *says* he doesn't know."